# What problems can occur, if i move a file to a different folder and somebody else changes it?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm currently working on a subject which targets file locations in a project.
The goal is to add a better and more clear structure to the project and it's classes.

My colleague had a concern which i have never thought off.

Does git have a problem when i relocate a file in a different folder and another colleague changes it?

For example:

1. I make a new branch cloned from development.
2. I relocate the files to a new/different folder (/old/test.cs to /new/test.cs)
3. He changes the file on a different branch and starts a pull request.

Because we're working with Bit-Bucket and Pull Requests he cannot pull my changes until they're merged.

So does git have a problem with this or should this work without any conflicts?

Maybe this is an odd question, but i've honestly never thought about that.

Kind regards.

Comment: This is usually fine! Just make sure you don't significantly change the files in the same commit that moved them, otherwise Git's rename detection might not see that they are actually the same file in a different location.

Comment: Thank your for your response. I will tell him that and maybe make a quick test on a different branch. :-)